# Fast test for audio file bitrate

Tags: shell-script, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to identify files with high/low bitrate in my audio collection using a shell script. Doing `file test.mp3` is very fast:

```
$time file test.mp3 
test.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo

real    0m0.027s
```

However, `file` doesn't show the bitrate for .m4a files:

```
$time file test.m4a 
test.m4a: ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio

real    0m0.056s
```

I tried using `exiftool` and `ffprobe`, but they seem to be at least 10 times slower:

```
$time exiftool test.m4a 
Avg Bitrate                     : 131 kbps

real    0m0.532s
```

```
$time ffprobe test.m4a 
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)

real    0m0.621s
```

This is only about 100 files/minute, which is quite slow. Is there a faster way to find a bitrate of m4a files? I understand that `ffprobe` checks the stream data rather than tags so it's more precise than `file`. I'm OK with a less precise bitrate value as long as it's fast.

Answer (score 3):

My experience with these tags is that they're not *approximate*, they're *wrong*, especially for older VBR-encoded MP3 files, like, off by a factor of 8, sometimes. In general, things aren't better for MP4 (which pretty much uses variable bitrate; but "MP4" contains a *large* family of [very different audio codecs with different qualities at the same rate](https://web.archive.org/web/20200202080247/https://people.xiph.org/%7Egreg/opus/ha2011/)!)

That has to do with two things:

1. Audio that you compress for storage (not for sending via e.g. a digital radio station, a phone or as audio track in an online video) doesn't *need* to be compressed at a constant bit rate – that just makes no sense. Representing "silence" simply  needs fewer bits than representing a complex moment in a multi-instrumental song. So, selecting one bitrate and sticking to it for every chunk of audio simply is either going to waste a lot of space, or to sound worse when you need more bits than average, and be good in passages where you don't notice it. Therefore, having a "sensible" constant bitrate is going to sound bad. Using a very high constant bitrate is something that we did around 2000 a lot, but it still sounded bad – simply because a lot of the encoders were simply not very good. I swear, around 2002 I could tell the different MP3 encoders I used for ripping my CDs apart by the audible artifacts – at 160 kbps. Not good; these were buggy beasts.
2. If, instead of constant bitrate, the encoder was set to constant quality, what bitrate do you then put into a header? The minimum ? Makes no sense, if there's a few milliseconds of silence in the song. The maximum? Makes no sense, that might just be the moment the drummer hit the crash cymbal. The average? Makes only slightly more sense, as some songs are just better to encode than others, but assuming you have songs at a relatively constant volume, genre, speed, production quality, spatial separation, in other words, if all your music sounds the same: You could get roughly the same by dividing the file size in bits by the duration of the song. That should be fast!

With that out of the way: the main time `ffprobe` spends is typically loading and internal setup; you can hide that well using @OleTange's GNU `parallel`:

```bash
# for bash, whose recursive globbing is off by default
# omit if on zsh
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

# run all ffprobe in parallel.
# GNU parallel takes care of keeping output in correct order
parallel --eta \
  ffprobe \
    -loglevel fatal \
    -output_format json \
    -show_entries format=bit_rate:format=filename \
  ::: **/*.mp4 **/*.mp3 **/*.mpeg **/*.mpc **/*.wma **/*.opus **/*.ogg \
| jq  \
  '.[] | {(.filename): (.bit_rate|tonumber)} ' \
| jq --slurp \
  'reduce .[] as $i ({}; . * $i)' 
> allfiles.json
```

I tried, and for me this meant a speedup of ca 400%.

(the `jq` chain at the end is purely optional, but will give you a valid, nice-to-work-with document mapping file names to bit rates)